# catch exception when throw error using nodejs

Tags: node.js, error-handling, uncaught-exception

I want to build api resful, and I want to catch error when I throw error, but it is not working

controller.js

Article.findOne({_id: my_id}, function(err, article){

```
if(article === null){
   throw Error('Article is not found');
}else{
   res.status(200).json(article);
}
```

});

When my_id is not in database, I cant not catch error and response json app.js

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(200).json({
        'status' : 500,
        'messages' : err
    });

});
```

Comment: How are you catching the exception?? Simple `try.. catch` works in js.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to throw an error as it halts the execution of the whole script.

With express you can just pass the error to the `next` function and you error catcher will work.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Article.findOne({_id: my_id}, function(err, article) {
        if(article === null){
           var error = Error('Article is not found');
           next(error);
        }else{
           res.status(200).json(article);
        }
    });
});
```